# opencart multistore with seo url

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I'm using oc 1.5.6.4 with multistore and seo url. Now i have domain domain.com and store1.domain.com with seo url on. I'm using this

> RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]

to make the seo url works in store1.domain.com.

The problem is that now I can't see my store1.domain.com home page and it shows "The page you requested cannot be found". But if I take off that code, the seo url can not work.

So what should I do to make both multistore and the seo url works without adding the new sub domain in .htaccess manually. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set SEO URLS and Multi-Store Configuration

1. Add the SEO keywords to all products and categories (unique keywords).
2. Switch on SEO URLs - System>Settings>Server>Use SEO URLs. You only get this option on the DEFAULT store.
3. Edit the **.htaccess** file.

   `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

Also, Refer below threads

[SEO URLS and Multi-Store](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=53317)

[Enable-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart](http://themes.eshopalot.com/enable-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've done like it suggested but the problem is this RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] because my store shows "The page you requested cannot be found" when I use it. But wiyhout it, my seo url dont works. You can see it in http://engkong.yoobro.com/

Comment: After recheck, it was my mistake. I was using unnecessary RewriteCond and your answer is correct. Thank you.